# How to select third tab on same class name by selenium python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, web

I just jump into python programming. I couldn't solve this 
I tried to several ways

This is target site

```
<div class="base-components__BaseElement-sc-150tvch-0 sc-VigVT bJRDeW">
<ul role="tablist" class="tabs-header-container">
  <li role="presentation" class="tabheader slot-selector--week-tabheader slot-selector--3-week-tab-space">
    <a href="/groceries/en-GB/slots/delivery/2020-04-09?slotGroup=1" aria-selected="false" class="slot-selector--week-tabheader-link" role="tab" title="Between April 9th - 15th">Apr 09 - 15</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="tabheader slot-selector--week-tabheader slot-selector--3-week-tab-space">
    <a href="/groceries/en-GB/slots/delivery/2020-04-16?slotGroup=1" aria-selected="false" class="slot-selector--week-tabheader-link" role="tab" title="Between April 16th - 22nd">Apr 16 - 22</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="tabheader active slot-selector--week-tabheader slot-selector--3-week-tab-space">
    <a href="/groceries/en-GB/slots/delivery/2020-04-23?slotGroup=1" aria-selected="true" class="slot-selector--week-tabheader-link" role="tab" title="Between April 23rd - 29th">Apr 23 - 29</a>
  </li>
</ul></div>
```

and this is my python code

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.slot-selector--week-tabheader-link').[2].click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using find_element instead of [find_element**S**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector), find_element only finds the first one.

I like to find elements within elements, this finds the active LI and clicks on it.

```
list = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.tabs-header-container')
item = list.find_element_by_css_selector('.active')
item.click()
```

You can also find multiple elements and take the third one:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.slot-selector--week-tabheader-link')
links[2].click()
```

Comment: Great code. solve all of issue Thank you for help